# Quicker way to download files from FTP server in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ftp, download

Let's say I am browsing an ftp server, and there is a ton of files I want to download. Usually I go about it by
 `[Right-Click link]` + `[Click "Save link as.."]` + `[Click "Save"]`

While this works, imagine doing this for this for 200 files. Is there any smarter way to go about this?

Comment: what about using a real ftp client like FileZilla ?

Comment: Yes, use a dedicated FTP client. Browsers like Chrome offer only limited FTP features.

Answer (score 3):

### Chrome extensions

There are some Chrome extensions that allow you to select multiple links and then trigger the needed option through the context menu - I can name two: [uSelect iDownload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/uselect-idownload/ileabdhfjmgaognikmjgmhhkjffggejc) and [Linkclump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj).

Both extensions allow you to download several files at once, and setup multiple actions to perform after the download is complete.

PS: there are a lot of FTP clients out there that can be installed as Chrome extensions as well, so there's really not a strong enough reason not to use this instead of the above approach...  however, I'm trying to respond to the specific question as asked by the OP -- "*Is there any smarter way to go about [downloading files from a FTP server, instead of doing `[Right-Click link] + [Click "Save link as.."] + [Click "Save"]`*]?"